# Computation of relative path

Tags: javascript, relative-path

I am facing difficulty in understanding relative path concept, I have seen a part of code written as

```
../../abc/file/images/picutre/down.gif
```

how the relative path is computed

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with 'computed'? The path is relative to the path of the file where it's in.

Comment: http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relative path is a path relative to the working directory. In other words the starting point to look for files is from the working directory.

The "../" in a relative path means to go up one directory.

So lets say you're referencing the relative path `../../abc/file/images/picutre/down.gif` from an index.html page in the following structure :

```
http://someexampleurl.com/dir1/dir2/index.html
```

Your working directory when working from **index.html** is **/dir2** so taking into account that you're going up two levels, the browser expects the file to be at:

```
 http://someexampleurl.com/abc/file/images/picutre/down.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

> how the relative path is computed

Basically a relative path is a "map" from the directory that you are located to the file you need to include. Therefore, relative path is computed based on where you want to go.

For example you have a structure

```
/ (document root)
|--home.php
|--t.php
|--common
      |--header.php
      |--footer.php
|--support
      |--index1.php
|--privacy
|     |--index2.php
```

From `home.php` you need to include `header` and `footer`. Therefore your home code will look like

```
<?php
include("common/header.php"); // go one folder down (common) and grab the file header.php
include("common/footer.php"); // go one folder down (common) and grab the file footer.php
```

Now let say you are in `index1.php` in support and you need `header.php` and `footer.php`. You code will look like

```
<?php
include("../common/header.php"); // go one folder up (common) and grab the file header.php
include("../common/footer.php"); // go one folder up (common) and grab the file footer.php
```

Think folder inside folder as levels (level1, level2, etc)

**Note:** Be careful with relative paths something they are a pain.

Answer (score 0):

it says go back up two level (parent directory) "../../" from current location.

Answer (score 0):

So if we are on `https://example.com/my/path/here` and it loaded a file `../../abc/file/images/picutre/down.gif` then we would go up 2 directories because of the 2 `../`'s to `https://example.com/my`. Then we would go down to `/abc/file/images/picutre/down.gif`. So the final destination would be `https://example.com/my/abc/file/images/picutre/down.gif`

Answer (score 0):

1. down.gif is present in the same directory
2. / starts form root directory
3. ../ one directory back from current directory
4. ../../ two directory back from current directory